# How to import a excel file on button click using angular

Tags: html, angularjs, excel

We have a requirement of showing a excel file on click of a menu button.
[image]

On clicking new tab, i want to show the excel file which is stored on my local drive.
The excel file should look like this:

[image]

How can i achieve this using angular.Is there any library which can read/import excel file.? Or do i need to create table using HTML tags.?
Please suggest a way to achieve this

Comment: use https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx . its a JS libary

Answer (score 2):

you can use [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) to display excel data in html. check out [this](http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/) demo. just go through the documentation and follow the steps.

Comment: Excelent @IT13122256 Ranawaka R.A.S.M

Comment: Thank you for your help, just have a query I can only see data here. IS there a way i can see the entire excel sheet. I mean can i see the data the way it is shown in excel